# How to share variables between tests in TestNG?

Tags: automated-tests, testng, rest-assured

I have a test Login class, which has positive and negative tests for Login. Result for positive case - receive token in the response.

Also, I have another Functionality class, which has tests for some functionality, which is available for login users.

How to get token from positive Login test to functionality tests?

I have found only one solution:

- make a static variable token in the Login class
- after positive Login test, token variable should be init from response
- in all functionality tests dependency to Login positive test should be added

But it looks like adding dependency to all functionality tests is not a good idea.
Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution could be moving login functionality to a separate place and reusing it in ***Login*** and ***Functional*** tests. For example, you can extract a token before ***Functional*** tests using TestNG before annotations.

```
class RequestHelper {

  public static io.restassured.Response login(String username, String password) {
    Response response;
    //some code to get login response
    return response;
  }
}

class LoginTest {

 @Test
 public void shouldLogin() {
   Response loginResponse = RequestHelper.login("username", "password");
   //assertions that response is valid
 }
}

class FunctionalTest {

  private String token;

  @BeforeClass
  public void getToken(){
     Response response = RequestHelper.login("username", "password");
     //Extracting token from response here (depends on how token is returned)
     token = response.then().extract().jsonPath().getString("token");
  }

  @Test
  public void functionalTest(){
    //Use token here
  }
}
```

Also making ***Functional*** tests depend on success of positive ***Login*** tests can be a good idea too. This way you if positive ***Login*** tests fail ***Functional*** tests won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use TestNG's `ITestContext`.

For ex:

in test class,

```
    ctx.setAttribute("TOKEN", token);
```

in another class for the same test,

```
    String token = ctx.getAttribute("TOKEN");
```

Take a look at this example.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriverreusable-tests-testng/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in your runner xml file.
And
You can use properties external files for saving values.